# MonoTouch - equivalent of WinForms context menu

Tags: winforms, xamarin.ios, contextmenu

I'm developing an application in MonoTouch and looking to display a context menu when user taps various controls. 
Is there any suitable equivalent of WinForms ContextMenuStrip control in iOS world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `UIActionSheet`.  It is basically a popup with X number of buttons.

It is slightly nicer on the iPad, because you can see it in a Popover bubble.  You will see them in other places in other apps.  (Like in safari, hit the middle "send to" button on the bottom toolbar on the iPhone).

Here is [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).